# Display current Git branch in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio

It's quite annoying to work in the wrong branch when using Git (in TFS). Is there a way to configure Visual Studio to clearly display what branch that's currently active? Like, put it in the title bar?

Below is outdated. The newer version of the extension in the link can display the Git branch now. No need to hack anymore.

> If nothing exists maybe it could be possible to hack *[Labs →
> Visual Studio Extension: Customize Visual Studio Window Title](http://erwinmayer.com/labs/visual-studio-2010-extension-rename-visual-studio-window-title/)*
> (source code is at
> https://github.com/mayerwin/vs-customize-window-title). What is the
> code to get the current Git branch of the current project in Visual
> Studio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Git Source Control Provider](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c) displays the branch name in the *Pending Changes* tool window.

The [VSCommands extension](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/Features-SolutionBadges) adds the branch name to the Visual Studio 2013 title.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Install the [Rename Visual Studio Window](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f3f23845-5b1e-4811-882f-60b7181fa6d6) extension.

Go to *Tools* → *Options* → *Rename VS Window Title* → *Global rules*, under *Patterns* → *Solution*
in *xxx* mode, and add `[gitBranchName]` to the path.

Example: `[parentPath]\[gitBranchName]`

Update: They've changed the title of the extension to
[Customize Visual Studio Window Title](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mayerwin.RenameVisualStudioWindowTitle)

Comment: Is it literally "xxx mode"?

Comment: They changed the name to Customize VS Window Title, it was driving me nuts, I couldn't find it in options.  Search for Cust

Comment: For VS2019, where they've removed the traditional title bar, it can be brought back with:
Options > Environment > Preview Features > Use compact menu and search bar

Answer (score 9):

[ShowMyGitBranch](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eef160a-4765-4f6b-8064-31ecd16896c1) is a lightweight and straightforward solution for this. No configuration is required.

By the time I developed this extension I did not know VSCommands had a solution for this, so I did it with this very simple goal in mind.